# What is the proof of this equation? (Stochastic process)

Tags: stochastic-processes

$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)h(Y)]=\mathbb{E}[h(Y)\,\mathbb{E}[g(X)|Y]]$$

I am reading the book "[An Introduction to Stochastic Modeling](http://matap.dmae.upm.es/WebpersonalBartolo/Probabilidad/KarlinTaylorIntrodStochModeling.pdf)". This equation appears a lot but I can not see why.

Can anyone please provide some proofs and examples?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is only true under the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent given the sigma-algebra of $Y$; the equation you wrote in fact could be taken as the definition of this. As to why these particular RVs are conditionally independent in the context given, you would have to supply us with more information about where specifically in the book this is occurring.

Comment: @William I think you might be misreading the equation. It is valid as long as $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ are integrable, and follows from basic properties of conditional expectation.

Comment: Also, this is not really related to stochastic processes per se...

Comment: @ByronSchmuland $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent if and only if $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ are conditionally independent for any measurable $g,h$. But yeah it looks like I misread the braces -- that is not how I would write that equation.

Answer (score 2):

For any random variables $Z$ and $Y$ with $Z$ integrable we have $E(Z) = E[ E(Z\mid Y) ] $. Apply this to
$$Z:=g(X)h(Y)$$
and note that
$$E(g(X)h(Y)\mid Y ) = h(Y) E(g(X)\mid Y),
$$
since $h(Y)$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(Y)$.